# Como destruir uma propriedade de um objeto dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, typescript, propriedade

Estou implementando uma `chain of responsabilities`, e, quando o objeto desejado é retornado, ele continua com as instâncias dos itens depois dele:

```
const ITEM_SELECIONADO = "EXEMPLO"

export interface ChainModelo{
  setNext(modelo: ChainModelo);
  next();
}

export class ExemploChain{
  modelo: ChainModelo | null;
  name:string = 'EXEMPLO';

  setNext(modelo: ChainModelo){
    this.modelo = modelo;
  }

  next(){
    if(ITEM_SELECIONADO !== name)
      return modelo.next();
    return this;
  }
}
```

Em suma, as instâncias de diversos objetos sem utilidade ficam armazenados na memória até que o objeto seja destruído. Para contornar o problema, modifiquei o método `next` para possuir o seguinte comportamento:

```
next(){
  if(ITEM_SELECIONADO !== name)
    return modelo.next();
  this.modelo = null;
  return this;
}
```

Mas o que eu queria era que essa propriedade fosse destruída, que não pudesse mais ser acessada, como se nem existisse. Há uma forma de remover uma propriedade ou comportamento de um objeto em Typescript ou JavaScript?

Comment: `delete this.modelo`

Comment: É exatamente isso, obrigado.

Comment: Bota em uma resposta, aí fecho a questão

Comment: Também tem outras opções: [deletando a propriedade com slice, a partir da sua posição](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)  ou simplesmente setando ele para `this.modelo = undefined;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) para remover propriedades dos objetos:

```
next(){
  if(ITEM_SELECIONADO !== name)
    return modelo.next();
  delete this.modelo;
  return this;
}
```